# Syntax error using multiple CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a rather complicated CTE that I'm attempting to incorporate into a stored procedure. It works when just operating straight from SQL Server Management Studio. When I try to create my stored procedure, I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spMyCrazyProc, Line 56
>   
> Incorrect syntax near ','.

What have I syntactically done incorrectly when trying to incorporate my CTE into a stored procedure?

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[spMyCrazyProc]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[spMyCrazyProc]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spMyCrazyProc
    @CompanyId  Int,
    @EmployeeIds varchar(MAX)
AS


;with SelectedEmployees as ( 
    select * from  vwEmployee e
        where e.CompanyId = @CompanyId 
            and (@EmployeeIds is null or @EmployeeIds='' or exists(select ce.SelectedEmployeeId from #myTmpTable ce where ce.SelectedEmployeeId=e.EmployeeId)
), MyStuffA as ( 
    select * from SelectedEmployees
)
select * from MyStuffA

GO
```

Comment: (As an aside, there's no way that code works outside of the stored procedure body, either. It would yield the exact same error. And also would yield a very similar error (just no longer pointing at a comma) if you only had one CTE. I suspect you missed the syntax error only because you've forced the text way off the screen to the right. I've left that that way after my edit to demonstrate why coding this way is such a problem. Indents and carriage returns are your friends. Run-on streams of consciousness that force you to scroll off the screen are not helpful to anyone.)

Comment: Also, 300+ lines? Really? I deal with some pretty complex queries, and I'm much more liberal with carriage returns than you are, and I don't remember the last time I dealt with any T-SQL over 100 lines long.

Comment: Yeah... I wasn't all that fond of the length, either. Our SSRS implementation required all the logic go into SQL rather than typical code. Lots of UNIONS, CASES, and even a CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sensible coding conventions and thinking about readability (indenting, carriage returns) would have yielded this simple error much more clearly. Your code with 500 character-wide lines removed:

```
;with SelectedEmployees as 
( 
    select * from  vwEmployee e
    where e.CompanyId = @CompanyId 
    and 
    (
      @EmployeeIds is null or @EmployeeIds='' or exists
      (
         select ce.SelectedEmployeeId from #myTmpTable ce 
          where ce.SelectedEmployeeId=e.EmployeeId
      )

----^----- oops! Missing closing paren here.

), MyStuffA as 
( 
  select * from SelectedEmployees
)
select * from MyStuffA
```

Comment: Is the `;` in front of the CTE correct when it's part of the procedure definition right after the procedure's `AS`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tend to use it always, because I never know who is going to copy the code and where they are going to paste it. But yes, it is valid immediately following `AS`, for example this works: `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.blat AS ;SELECT 1;` (though personally there would always be a `BEGIN` and `SET NOCOUNT ON;` after `AS` and before any other code in the procedure). A semi-colon is a statement terminator, and so is always valid (except when it actually terminates a statement when it shouldn't). For example,  `;;;;;;/*comment*/;;;SELECT 1;;;;SELECT 2;;;;;` works just fine...

Comment: The line was 158 characters, not 500 :P Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For someone coming from the Oracle and Postgres world, Microsoft (non)usage of the semicolon is *really* confusing (somethimes it's at the front, sometimes it's required to be at the end, sometimes it's not needed at all...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's never *required* at the front. However it is required at the end of the statement that *precedes* a CTE. So I always put it at the beginning because it doesn't cause any problems there, and I've had too many times where I didn't put it there, people copied and pasted into their own code (with no semi-colons), and got an error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [Also, statements *not* terminated with semi-colons *are* on the deprecation path. For backward compatibility reasons, it's not something they'd be wise to turn off at the drop of a hat](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx).